# Umbraco 7 Content editor randomly hangs when generating thumbnails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, iis-8.5

Umbraco 7.6.6, running under IIS 8.5 on fully patched Windows Server 2011 R2 Standard, 64bit.

Our content editors notice that often when they create a new article (which has some graphics specified) the system hangs after they try to browse to a different article... or indeed anywhere in the front-end site, too. It only affects them; other users are still able to browse and/or create content.

F12 dev tools shows that browser is pending the result of this type of call:

> http://whatever.com/media/1101/thumbnail_pmc-1x2.jpg?width=500&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first

If I try to view that thumbnail without the querystring data, it loads instantly... while the first call is still hanging in it's unresponsive tab:

> http://whatever.com/media/1101/thumbnail_pmc-1x2.jpg

DEBUG level Umbraco logs just show this:

```
 2017-10-10 17:02:53,120 [P2816/D6/T57] DEBUG Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - Begin request: http://whatever.com/media/1101/thumbnail_pmc-1x2.jpg?width=500&mode=max&animationprocessmode=first.
```

No errors in the umbraco logs, no errors in IIS logs, nothing in event viewer.

Best I can tell, something is going wonky in the browser. Can anybody please advise on how I can troubleshoot further?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that certain Umbraco users are experiencing this issue, but not others?

Comment: All of the content editors experience this from time to time. Several times a day, in fact. But the block only affects themselves, not other users. (For instance, while one content editor is blocked, another might go in and successfully create/edit an article and publish it successfully).

Comment: Are they high resolution images that are being uploaded?